# How do you run Gaussian's cubegen with multiple processes/threads?

Tags: computational-chemistry

The cubegen manual gives the signature of cubegen as:

`cubegen nprocs  kind  fchkfile  cubefile  npts  format cubefile2`

Where:

> nprocs
> Number of shared memory processors used for electrostatic potential calculations. A value of 0 is equivalent to 1 (it is the default). Note that this parameter must be included if other parameters are specified. Previously this parameter was used to specify the amount of memory to allocate. The GAUSS_MEMDEF environment variable should be used instead.

Which would seem to imply that setting `nprocs` > 1 would use multiple processes to speed up the cube file writing. However, in practice it doesn't seem to do anything. With Gaussian 16, Revision C.01, the following commands:

`cubegen 1 MO=HOMO file.fchk file.HOMO.cube 0`

and

`cubegen 8 MO=HOMO file.fchk file.HOMO.cube 0`

are treated identically. In both cases, only one processes/thread is used (from `ps -o nlwp`), CPU usage (from `top`) peaks at only 100%, and the commands take the same time to execute (~ 2 min).

Even more confusingly, in Gaussian 09, `cubegen 8 MO=HOMO file.fchk file.HOMO.cube 0` does use 8 CPUs (`ps -o nlwp`), but the execution is significantly slower than when using only 1?

Is this a bug in cubegen, or am I misinterpreting how `nprocs` is supposed to work?

---

### Update

As suggested by jxzou, setting `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=n` does actually set the number of threads in cubegen 16, the `nprocs` parameter seems to have no effect.

However, increasing the number of threads above 1 still results in a massive slowdown. For an example fchk file (~1.3 GB, ~100 atoms), running with one thread takes 3 m 21 s, with only 2 threads it increases to 12 m 37 s?

Comment: I don't use Gaussian at all, but do develop parallel software so I'll note that using more processes does not necessarily mean a faster solution, and can indeed lead to slower running if you use too many processes for too small a problem. What is "too many" and "too small" will be code, problem, computational architecture dependent and possibly phase of the moon dependent, so a good number can only be found by experiment (but experience can inform that). I would rerun your 09 case with 2 procs and 4 procs and see what happens.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong Stack Exchange. Try Matter Modelling SE.

Comment: @IanBush this is a good point. However, it seems that any number of procs above 1 results in a noticeable slow-down that worsens the more procs you use. The molecules I've tested are non-trivial (> 50 atoms, fchk = ~400 MB), but maybe they're still too small to benefit from any speed up...

Comment: @Tensor think you might be right. Hadn't heard of matter modelling before and saw other cubegen questions on here (which I guess predate matter mod.?). Is there a way to migrate?

Comment: Have you tried running `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` firstly, then running `cubegen 8 blabla`

Comment: A good suggestion! Yes this does have an effect, I'll update